# Wrong values on Summary of Social Actions?

Tags: linkedin-api

It seems that the LinkedIn API returns incorrect values when retrieving a comment's summary of social actions.

I did a `GET` request on `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn%3Ali%3Acomment%3A%28urn%3Ali%3Aactivity%3A6546403695196811264%2C6546405316437790720%29`

Here is the API response body:

```
{
  'commentsSummary': {
    'totalFirstLevelComments': 0,
    'aggregatedTotalComments': 0
  },
  '$URN': 'urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:6546403695196811264,6546405316437790720)',
  'likesSummary': {
    'likedByCurrentUser': False,
    'aggregatedTotalLikes': 0,
    'totalLikes': 0
  },
  'target': 'urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:6546403695196811264,6546405316437790720)'
}
```

And the expected response body:

```
{
  'commentsSummary': {
    'totalFirstLevelComments': 3,
    'aggregatedTotalComments': 3
  },
  '$URN': 'urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:6546403695196811264,6546405316437790720)',
  'likesSummary': {
    'likedByCurrentUser': True,
    'aggregatedTotalLikes': 2,
    'totalLikes': 2
  },
  'target': 'urn:li:comment:(urn:li:activity:6546403695196811264,6546405316437790720)'
}
```

Here are the response headers to help the LinkedIn team debugging:

```
{
  'X-LI-ResponseOrigin': 'RGW',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
  'Content-Length': '327',
  'Date': 'Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:49:38 GMT',
  'X-Li-Fabric': 'prod-lor1',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'X-Li-Pop': 'prod-efr5',
  'X-LI-Proto': 'http/1.1',
  'X-LI-UUID': 'i07XV5tIqRWAdyFKiSsAAA==',
  'Set-Cookie': 'lidc="b=OB36:g=1847:u=345:i=1560858577:t=1560936475:s=AQEK0vHcIcV0LWfWF-E4uJW6AanRPr4r"',
  'X-LI-Route-Key': '"b=OB36:g=1847:u=345:i=1560858577:t=1560936475:s=AQEK0vHcIcV0LWfWF-E4uJW6AanRPr4r"'
}
```

Any explanation about the API response?

Best regards.

Comment: You may want to submit this request to linkedin.zendesk.com

Comment: Thanks for the link, I just submitted a ticket. Initially the LinkedIn support team told me to post it on StackOverflow...

Comment: @mykel were you able to get a response from linkedin.zendesk.com? The LinkedLn API support though StackOverflow seems to be insufficient.